# CSS: wrapping around text inside a drawn circle using CSS

Tags: html, css, geometry, word-wrap

I am using this CSS code to draw circles:

```
circle {
    background: #f00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin:5px;
}
```

Using this in `html` I can draw 3 circles side-by-side with text inside them:

```
 <circle>Text1</circle>
 <circle>Text2</circle>
 <circle>Text3</circle>
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Now if I want to add more text in side the middle circle this is what happens:

```
<circle>Text1</circle>
<circle>Text2 and more</circle>
<circle>Text3</circle>
```

[image]

whoever, I want 'Text2 and more` to stay inside the second circle and just wraps around. How can I achieve that?

NOTE: I don't want to use `display: table-cell` as it doesn't work nicely on responsive sites and does not let circles wrap around and stay on top of each other if the view page is very narrow.

Comment: `<circle>`... is that SVG or just some custom Element tag name of yours you found fit to use?

Comment: It is just a name I picked it could be any name, it is not SVG.

Comment: You should not use invalid tag names. If you really want to notify the browser of such custom tags you should do it using JavaScript and use a *dash* like `app-circle`. `<circle>` is an SVG element, not a valid HTML5 tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line-height is causing this. I've adjusted your CSS.

```css
circle span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90px;
}
circle {
  background: #f00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<circle><span>Text 1</span></circle>
<circle><span>Text 2 and more</span></circle>
<circle><span>Text 3</span></circle>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now the 3 circles are attached to each other, while I need some space between them.

Comment: The other problem is you have changed the `display` from `inline-block` to `table-cell` that does not work if you have a responsive cite!

Comment: Snippet is adjusted

Comment: If I copy and run the code on JSfiddle it doesn't work! https://jsfiddle.net/5458ucba/

Comment: I don't know why! When I run it here it works fine! But I will have a look at JSfiddle to see if I can find out why it is different there!

Comment: Fixed the code. Added position: relative to circle. https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/k3b6v3au/

Comment: Great. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

This may suit your needs better, line-height is your man issue, but this will center your text properly, you may want to adjust the height/width/padding, padding should be 25% of the height

```
<div class="circle">
  <div class="text">
    hello world i am a circle
   </div>
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <div class="text">
    hello world
   </div>
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <div class="text">
    hello superman i am a red sun
   </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.circle {
    background: #f00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:25px;
    position:relative;
}
.text{
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the line-height causes the wierd offset. You could use flexbox to center the text within the circle.

```
<div class="circles">
    <circle>Text1</circle>
    <circle>Text2 has more text</circle>
    <circle>Text3</circle>
</div>
```

---

```
.circles{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
circle {
    display: flex;
    margin:5px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #f00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This does not work on responsive sites. If I make the page narrower the circles get deformed and change to ovals!